# How can I add "namespace" to request in node soap

Tags: node.js, soap, npm, namespaces

I created web service object from wsdl file and call it like in below. I also print result. this code does not work. web server returns error. because, request has not namespace.

```
soap.createClient(__dirname + '/wsdl/getCustomerDetails.wsdl', function(err, client) {
.
.
var params=  {"custId":"123"};
client.getCustomerDetails.getCustomerDetailsPort.getCustomerDetails(params,function(err,result){
    console.log("lastRequest:"+client.lastRequest);
    if (err != null)
        console.log("error:"+JSON.stringfy(error));

});

}
```

here what I see in the last request

```
<soap:...  xmlns:tns="http://example.com/api/getCustomerDetails/V01" >
....
  <soap:Body>
     <getCustomerDetailsRequest>
         <custId>123</custId>
     </getCustomerDetailsRequest>
  </soap:Body>...
```

but it has to be

```
<soap:...  xmlns:tns="http://example.com/api/getCustomerDetails/V01" >
    ....
   <soap:Body>
     <tns:getCustomerDetailsRequest>
        <tns:custId>123</tns:custId>
     </tns:getCustomerDetailsRequest>
   </soap:Body>...
```

as you see, soap module does not add `tns` namespace to the request. I tried `var params=  {"tns:custId":"123"};`, it adds namespace to the parameter, but still it does not add namespace to the request, `getCustomerDetailsRequest`. because of that, I get `Unexpected element getCustomerDetailsRequest found. Expected {http://example.com/api/getCustomerDetails/V01}getCustomerDetailsRequest`.

how can I force to add this namespace to the method itself ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found how I can do that. I think it does not work in default because of a bug in "soap" module. In default, it does not add namespace to the request body. "soap" uses "tns" in default as namespace. there is an option in wsdlOptions. it is `overrideRootElement`. If you try to override `overrideRootElement` with `tns`, it does not add `tns` to the request body. You have to use different namespace in `overrideRootElement`. Here my solution,

I first create my `wsdlOptions` object.

```
var wsdlOptions = {
  "overrideRootElement": {
    "namespace": "myns",
    "xmlnsAttributes": [{
      "name": "xmlns:myns",
      "value": "http://example.com/api/getCustomerDetails/V01"
    }]
  }
};
```

and then use it when I create soap client,

```
soap.createClient(__dirname + '/wsdl/getCustomerDetails.wsdl',wsdlOptions, function(err, client) {
.
.
.
}
);
```

It makes request body uses `myns` as namespace of root element. Now, I have to modify parameters' namespace, so I defined parameters as

```
var params=  {"myns:custId":"123"};
```

now, It creates request as

```
<soap:...  xmlns:tns="http://example.com/api/getCustomerDetails/V01" >
    ....
   <soap:Body>
     <myns:getCustomerDetailsRequest xmlns:myns="http://example.com/api/getCustomerDetails/V01">
        <myns:custId>123</tns:custId>
     </myns:getCustomerDetailsRequest>
   </soap:Body>...
```

and, now webserver accepts it.

keep in mind, even `tns` is defined in the root, it is not added to the request body automatically. Also, if you try to override it in `wsdlOptions` by `tns` again, it still does not work. You have to use different value as namespace, like `myns`

Comment: How I call with request library with pass json instead xml?
I have problem with xmlns

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day! I was on the edge to provide the Soap XML as raw, which I'd hate to do so.

Comment: How to add multiple namespaces ?

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani was you able to add multiple namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

I dwelt sometime on this problem until I saw that the lib get the namespaces from the parsed WSDL (this.wsdl.xmlnsInEnvelope)

```
xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
        '<' + envelopeKey + ':Envelope ' +
        xmlnsSoap + ' ' +
        'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
        encoding +
        this.wsdl.xmlnsInEnvelope + '>' +
```

Then I saved the WSDL inside my project (loading from there) and inserted the namespace I wanted. That worked for me.