# node-soap adding namespace to envelope

Tags: soap, node-soap

I am trying to consume this soap service: http://testws.truckstop.com:8080/v13/Posting/LoadPosting.svc?singleWsdl with node-soap, but the client is mangling the namespaces and I have been unable to find a working solution.

I believe the answer is to either add a namespace to the soap envelope, or overwrite the soap envelope.

Using `Soap UI`, the request should look like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:v11="http://webservices.truckstop.com/v11" 
xmlns:web="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v11:GetLoads>
         <v11:listRequest>
            <web:IntegrationId>integrationId</web:IntegrationId>
            <web:Password>password</web:Password>
            <web:UserName>username</web:UserName>
         </v11:listRequest>
      </v11:GetLoads>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However, when I do:

```
client = soap.createClient(url);
let query = {
        listRequest: {
            Password: password,
            UserName: username,
            IntegrationId: integrationId
        }
    };
let results = client.GetLoads(query);
```

The client generates this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
        xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" 
        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
        xmlns:tns="http://webservices.truckstop.com/v11" 
        xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices.Posting" 
        xmlns:q2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices.Objects" 
        xmlns:q3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices.Posting" 
        xmlns:q4="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices.Objects" 
        xmlns:q5="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices.Posting" 
        xmlns:q6="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices.Objects" 
        xmlns:q7="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices.Posting" 
        xmlns:q8="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices.Objects" 
        xmlns:q9="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices.Posting" 
        xmlns:q10="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices.Objects" 
        xmlns:q11="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices.Posting" 
        xmlns:q12="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices.Objects">
        <soap:Body>
            <GetLoads xmlns="http://webservices.truckstop.com/v11">
                <listRequest>
                    <ns1:IntegrationId>integrationId</ns1:IntegrationId>
                    <ns1:Password>password</ns1:Password>
                    <ns1:UserName>usernam</ns1:UserName>
                </listRequest>
            </GetLoads>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

This fails because `IntegrationId`, `Password` and `UserName` need `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices`, but the namespace isn't referenced in the envelope.

I've tried updating the client to add the namespace as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740415/namespace-for-array-field-in-node-soap-client-node-js):

```
client.wsdl.definitions.xmlns.ns1 = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices";
client.wsdl.xmlnInEnvelope = client.wsdl._xmlnsMap();
```

I can see the namespace in `client.wsdl.xmlnInEnvelope`, but it doesn't seem to change the actual generated xml.

Is there another step required to refresh the client to use the updated envelope?

I also tried [overriding the root element as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933494/how-can-i-add-namespace-to-request-in-node-soap):

```
        var wsdlOptions = {
            //namespaceArrayElements: "xmlns:ns1=http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices"

            "overrideRootElement": {
                "namespace": "xmlns:tns",
                "xmlnsAttributes": [{
                    "name": "xmlns:tns",
                    "value": "http://webservices.truckstop.com/v11"
                }, {
                    "name": "xmlns:ns1",
                    "value": "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices"
                }]
            }
        };
        this.loadPostClient = soap.createClient(this.tsConfig.loadPostUrl, wsdlOptions);
```

This changes the root body element:

```
<soap:Body>
    <xmlns:tns:GetLoads 
        xmlns:tns="http://webservices.truckstop.com/v11" 
        xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices">
        <listRequest>
            <ns1:IntegrationId>integrationId</ns1:IntegrationId>
            <ns1:Password>password</ns1:Password>
            <ns1:UserName>username</ns1:UserName>
        </listRequest>
    </xmlns:tns:GetLoads>
</soap:Body>
```

But the remote server doesn't understand.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer was correct all along](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740415/namespace-for-array-field-in-node-soap-client-node-js)

It wasn't working for me due to autocomplete and similar fields

```
client.wsdl.xmlnInEnvelope = client.wsdl._xmlnsMap();
```

Should have been:

```
client.wsdl.xmlnsInEnvelope = client.wsdl._xmlnsMap();
```

I left out an `s` and was setting *xmlnInEnvelope* instead of *xmln**s**InEvelope*

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few years, but I ran into a similar need of adding custom attributes to the soap envelope and wanted to give an alternative.

As of this writing, that `_xmlnsMap()` is a [private method](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/5fc0710b22043ce4f1d473e0a4edecc718898ec0/src/wsdl/index.ts#L1284) on the WSDL class so you can use it at your own risk.  I always take private methods as subject to change from the developer without any notice to the library consumers so I wanted to find another way and turns out its possible.

**TL;DR - Create your own WSDL class instance and pass it to your own Client class instance.**

- Use the [open_wsdl](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/5fc0710b22043ce4f1d473e0a4edecc718898ec0/src/wsdl/index.ts#L1361) method to bring in your WSDL
- Use the callback to build your own custom attributes in a concatenated string.
- Assign the attributes to the public `xmlnsInEnvelope` property.
- return the updated WSDL instance (I used a promise).

```js
const fetchWSDL = new Promise<WSDL>((resolve, reject) => {
      // method that returns a WSDL instance from a url/file path
      open_wsdl(this.wsdl, (err: any, wsdl?: WSDL) => {
        // Build custom attributes
        if (wsdl && wsdl.definitions.xmlns) {
          const xmlns: { [key: string]: string } = {
           [your namespaces]: 'values',
          };

          // turn your custom attributes map into a single concatenated string 
          let str = '';
          for (const alias in xmlns) {
            const ns = xmlns[alias];
            str += ' xmlns:' + alias + '="' + ns + '"';
          }

          // Leverage public attribute on WSDL instance to apply our custom attributes
          wsdl.xmlnsInEnvelope = str;

          resolve(wsdl);
        }
        reject(err);
      });
    });
```

Use the updated WSDL instance to create your own client.
*NOTE:  the `createClient` method is just a convenience wrapper for creating a WSDL instance and returning a new Client instance.*

```js
const ModifiedWSDL = await fetchWSDL;

// Create client with our modified WSDL instance
this.client = new Client(ModifiedWSDL)

// adjust your Client instance as needed
```

A bit more code that the OP, but hopefully more in line with `node-soap` types and safer to use if you plan to upgrade.